# Como recorrer un arreglo en un objeto

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, arraylist, objeto

Estoy intentando mostrar unas imágenes que meto en un arreglo, pero al hacer un .map no me renderizan o solo se muestra la primer imagen, como podría mostrar las imágenes que introduzca?

Aca es otro componente que se llama Card aqui pongo las imagenes e intento hacer un map

```
      <LogosContainer>
        {infoCard.map((lg) => (
          <img src={lg.logos} alt="" />
        ))}
      </LogosContainer>
```

Este el el objeto donde tengo el componente portafolio y aqui tengo los logos son las imagenes que intento recorrer

```
const Portafolio = () => {
  const [infoCard] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      titulo: "hola",    
      // Array de imagenes
      logos: [LogoCSS, LogoHTML],
    },
  ]);
```

Aqui en logos no logro que se renderizan mis imagenes, ya intente con una funcion al igual no me quedo

```
   <CardContainer>
        {infoCard.map((info) => (
          <CardProject
            key={info.id}
            titulo={info.titulo}
        
            // Logos que contiene el array
            logos={info.logos}
          />
        ))}
      </CardContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta la estructura de tu state. Logos es un arreglo con las imágenes, por lo que lo que debes recorrer es ese arreglo.

```
{infoCard.map.map((item, index) => (
   <React.Fragment key={index}>
      <p>item.id</p>
      <p>item.titulo</p>

      {item.logos.map((logo, idx) => (....))}
   </React.Fragment>
))}
```

Como recomendación, trata de usar siempre un identificador único (`key`) para evitar conflictos entre componentes :)

Nos comentas que tal te va!

Answer (score 0):

como logos es un array deberias de poner la posición del array que quieres, [0] para que aparezca LogoCSS o [1] para que aparezca LogoHTML

```
<LogosContainer>
   {infoCard.map((lg) => (
      <img src={lg.logos[1]} alt="" />
   ))}
</LogosContainer>
```